# How can i find the path, filename and foldername of an "for /R"?

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I've written a batch-file, which renames all the PDF-files in the current folder and all its subfolders.

There are problems...

1. When I use `For /R %%I` I cannot find the path of the file, name and foldername.
2. When I don't use the above, it only finds in the current folder but the script works.
3. I only know the `For %%i` command to be able to use `set foldername=%%i` which is probably not how I'm supposed to do it. I now need multiple `do set*` in order to write each piece of information.

The result i want it from a pdf in path: C:\Users\Downloads\AREA 1\xyyz.pdf to automatically rename to C:\Users\Downloads\AREA 1\AREA 1_xyyz.pdf when the script is in the map C:\Users\Downloads
And preferably move the file over afterwards.
Yet I cannot seem to be able to command the file itself when using `For /R`.

When using the `For /R` command I cannot seem to access the right filename, mapname and filepath in order to change it's name.

```bash
echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "folderpath=%~dp0"

cd %folderpath%
for /r %%I in ("*.pdf") do ( for %%i in (.) do ( (set fname=%%i) & for %%I in (.) do ( (set fldnm=%%~nxI) & call :rename ) ) )
@pause
goto :eof

:rename
echo "%fldnm%_%fname%"
ren "%fname%" "%fldnm%_%fname%"
@pause
goto :eof

endlocal
pause
```

Comment: How is `cmd` supposed to distinguish between the two instances of `%%I`? First step would be to change the metavariable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what your *code* does... However, this solution does what your *description* specify:

**EDIT:** Small *rename* problem fixed

```
echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "folderpath=%~dp0"

cd %folderpath%
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /B /S *.pdf') do (
   set "fldnm=%%~pI"
   for %%i in ("!fldnm:~0,-1!") do (
      ren "%%~fI" "%%~ni_%%~nI%%~xI"
   )   
)

@pause
goto :eof
```

Comment: It works but when there's only one pfd in a folder, it the result is C:\Users\Downloads\AREA 1\AREA1_AREA 1_xyyz.pdf in stead of C:\Users\Downloads\AREA 1\AREA 1_xyyz.pdf 

The why? and what it does?
I am used to getting a dossier with multiple files in each folder, nicely sorted. Yet our program doesn't allow folders to be uploaded. To keep the dossier fairly manageble to read, I would like to be able to see at the pdf-file (which i later have to move and upload), where it was located.
Probably need a better program, but thats not within my authority. So therefore this workaround.

Comment: Yes. This is a known problem when a `REN` command is executed inside a standard `FOR` or `FOR /R` loop. Sometimes an already renamed file is renamed again. The fix is change a `FOR /R` by a `FOR /F` with a `DIR /S /B` command inside. I changed the above code already...

Comment: So? Works correctly the new version?

Comment: After some testing I noticed that when using the "For /ff delims" there is another problem. Now when there's only 1 pdf-file in a folder, it doesn't change the name.

There are no more double renames, but it seems to skip files.

Comment: That's very strange! Please, open a cmd.exe window at the folder and execute `dir /B /S *.pdf`  The files displayed by this command _should be_ the same files renamed by the Batch file...

Comment: Remade the batch-file from scratch after trying your execute. Somehow it now works and I really can't see a mistake in the first one. 

Anyways, it works!!! Thanks to you.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

@Aacini original answer with added 'double-rename'-protection.
The same can be used on Aacini's updated answer without for/R.

The original name is saved in a variable, try to delete the rename prefix from the variable  and try to delete the original name from the variable.
If the variable is now empty it is no longer defined and the rename must be done.

```
echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "folderpath=%~dp0"

cd %folderpath%
for /R %%I in ("*.pdf") do (
   set "fldnm=%%~pI"
   for %%i in ("!fldnm:~0,-1!") do (
      set "RenDone=%%~nI"
      set "RenDone=!RenDone:%%~ni_=!"
      set "RenDone=!RenDone:%%~nI=!"
      if not defined RenDone ren "%%~fI" "%%~ni_%%~nI%%~xI"
   )   
)

@pause
goto :eof
```